# Run Java method from a C++ program

Tags: java, c++

So, I want to use C++ to write an editor for my research, but the program that would receive the .txt generated by the editor is already written in Java. Is there a way for me to call the main.java method from my c++ program(since I'd have to pass in the .txt file as a parameter I guess I'd have to do so by compiling the java src code at runtime)?

Answer (score 0):

It it possible to run a java method using C++ have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/).
If you just want to launch your java program then you don't need JNI.

```
system("java -jar program.jar");
```